# Value Will Set properly, but Get receives Null

Tags: actionscript-3, get, null, set

So, I have successfully grabbed a value out of an XML document and set it into a separate class called "AddCommas."  The trace functions have shown me that it sets properly.

For more details, my objective is to take the language indicator ("fr" for french or "en" for english), set it inside the appropriate class and into a variable I will use.  Now, I am using this variable to be used in an if statement; which will help me format a number properly (commas, decimals, spaces) per the clients request.

However, my problem is when I try to get the value to use it.  It always comes back as Null.  I have placed traces all over my program trying to pinpoint when this happens, but I cannot find it. Here's the code...

The pull from the XML file and into the set (this works fine, but I am adding it for your benefit in case I missed something)

```
 public var commaHold = new AddCommas();
    localLanguage = xmlObj.localLanguage;
    trace("localLanguage + " + localLanguage);
    commaHold.setLanguage(localLanguage); // Set Language
   //More code follows...
```

This is the set function istelf...

```
public function setLanguage(localLanguage:String){
langHold = localLanguage;
trace("Set Language =  " + langHold); //This always shows a successful set
}
```

Now am I wrong in thinking that in AS3, once langHold in my AddCommas class has been set I should be able to use it without calling a get within the function I am using the If Statement in, right?  Such as this?

```
var language = langHold;
if (language == "en"){
trace("Language is = " + language); // More code follows afterwards and as of now, this shows NULL
```

Now, I have attempted plenty of Get functions to add the language variable in the call itself to this function and it's always the same.  Am I missing some fundamentals here?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect a string comparison you need to use quotes, unless en is a String variable since langHold is a String, like:

```
if (language == "en"){
```

Consider modifying the set function to use the as3 keyword like:

```
private var _language:String;

public function set language(value:String):void {
     _language = value;
     //do other stuff here if necessary, put a breakpoint on the line above
}

public function get language():String{
     return _language;
     //put a breakpoint on the line above
}
```

You should be able to see when any instance of your class has the property changed.  The only other issue I can think of is it is not the same instance of the class and therefore doesn't share the property value you set earlier.  In the debugger you can check the "hashCode" or "address" it shows for this to see if it changes when it hits the breakpoints.

Here's a sample Singleton structure in AS3 (this all goes in one file):

```
package com.shaunhusain.singletonExample
{

    public class SingletonExample
    {
        private static var instance:SingletonExample;

        public static function getIntance():SingletonExample
        {
            if( instance == null ) instance = new SingletonExample( new SingletonEnforcer() );
            return instance;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param se Blocks creation of new managers instead use static method getInstance
         */
        public function SingletonExample(se:SingletonEnforcer)
        {
        }
    }
}

internal class SingletonEnforcer {public function SingletonEnforcer(){}}
```

using this single shared instance from any other class would look something like this:

```
private var singletonInstance:SingletonExample = SingletonExample.getInstance();
```

Comment: In the actual code, I am comparing it with a static variable that is equal to en.  I am sorry for the error when I posted this question, but thank you for your reply and for making me aware of it.

Comment: yah thought that may have just been a copy paste one, but you never know.  I would suggest using a setter getter pair then debugging should be a bit easier, I'll add an example.

Comment: You are right, it is not the same instance of the class because I am setting in one class and getting in another.  Is there anyway that I can correct this issue, because it is currently not possible to use the same class to set and get.  It's a project that was given to us that we are now modifying.

Comment: Depending on the relationship between the two classes that need to interact with the instance you have two options, option 1 is to create the instance in one class and pass it to the other class, if one is a child of the other (like you make object2 in object1) then this is simplest.  You can also consider using a Singleton pattern for the class this way there is only one instance ever, it depends on your use case.

Comment: I really like the SingletonExample you gave me.  I have gone ahead and implemented it, but now I am receiving a 1061 error, that getInstance() is undefined in a Static Class.  However, I have triple checked my spelling and it all looks fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I ended up finding another Singleton example and the error disappeared.  I still give you all the credit for helping me even discover the Singleton solution.  Everything you said was spot on and in my solution below that I modified I still gave you credit.  Thanks for all of your help!  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Fridian thanks for the cred glad I could help, I'll see if I can get my answer fixed too thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

ShaunHusain's theory of using a Singleton was the perfect solution I needed.  However, his code gave me a bizarre 1061 error and my format and code appeared to be error free.  Regardless, I looked up another way to use a Singleton as follows that worked perfectly for me.  Honestly, Shaun's code should work for anyone and I have no idea why it wasn't.  I am perfectly willing to admit that it was probably a typo on my end that I just did not see.

I ended up embedding the Set and Get within the Singletons class and used it as an intermediary to hold the information I needed.  It worked perfectly.

```
package chart {

    import chart.*;
    //

    public class StaticInstance  {

        private static var instance:StaticInstance;
        private static var allowInstantiation:Boolean;
        private var language:String;

        public static function getInstance():StaticInstance {
        if (instance == null) {
            allowInstantiation = true;
            instance = new StaticInstance();
            allowInstantiation = false;
            }
        return instance;
        }

        public function StaticInstance():void {
        if (!allowInstantiation) {
            throw new Error("Error: Instantiation failed: Use StaticInsance.getInstance() instead of new.");
            }
        }

        public function setLanguage(_language:String):void{
            language = _language;
            trace("language set = " + language);
        }
        public function getLanguage():String{
            return language;
        }
    }
}
```

This code allowed me to hold the data and call upon it again from two different classes.  It's a very hack job instead of just being able to pass on the variable from function to function, but in my case we didn't create this file, we are modifying it and attempting to do things beyond the original scope of the project.

Thanks again for your help Shaun!  I hope this helps other people!